# "drush cron" doesn't work anymore after moving the site to a new server

Tags: 8, drush

After moving a site to a new server, `drush cron` stopped working and now I am getting the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFound]
>   Command "cron" is not defined.

What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose, you already checked the version of Drush, that the root exists and a site is defined for the URI?

Comment: yes, I am running drush 9.2, I check the root path and the URI

Comment: To make things work, locally on my computer it works

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fairly simple to solve.

I had forgotten to create a settings.php for each site. I was able to find out by running the following command:

```
drush --local -d -r /var/www/testproject/build/html status
```

And from the output I was able to see:

```
[debug] Could not find a Drupal settings.php file at sites/default/settings.php. [0.14 sec, 10.8 MB]
```

That was it